# How to iterate through bytes in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, byte

I'm trying to iterate through bytes in python.
I have:

```
new[0]=b'\x00'
```

but I want to iterate from `'\x00'` to `'\xFF'` in this `new[0]` element in a `for` loop. I mean:

```
new[0]=b'\x01'
new[0]=b'\x02'
```

My target is not to view bytearray, but to change the first byte in this statement:

```
XX:32:38:B3:89:E9:D2:E6:88:1F:FF:A9:96:AF:26:CB:C6:06:2F:E0:08:21:7C:12:4D:31
```

I want to change `XX` by iterating through bytes.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> arr = bytearray()
>>> arr.append(1)
>>> arr
bytearray(b'\x01')
>>> arr.append(2)
>>> arr
bytearray(b'\x01\x02')
>>> arr[0]
1           
>>> arr[1]
2
>>> arr[1] = 3
>>> arr
bytearray(b'\x01\x03')

>>> arr = bytearray()
>>> _=list(map(arr.append, range(0,256)))
>>> print(arr)
bytearray(b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff')
```